# Connection refused en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola esto es algo curioso espero y me puedan ayudar un poco...

Tengo una pagina donde registran cuentas a una base de datos, 
el codigo funciona porque ya esta funcionando.

este funciona y registra cuentas perfectamente en el hosting donde comenze un hosting gratuito, 000webhost.

pero migre a uno de paga para tener mi dominio .com y demas

total no me funciona en ese hosting me da el siguiente error>
[04-May-2019 16:34:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/wepags/public_html/conexion.php on line 6

la linea 6:

$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $contrasena ) or die ("Error conection");

como ya les he dicho no pienso que sea error en el codigo puesto que si funciona, 
solo que solo funciona en el hosting gratuito! me puse en contacto con el hosting de paga al cual migre, y no me solucionaron nada pues dicen que todo esta normal y no hay restricciones!

Comment: Por mera duda, si cambiaste tus credenciales de acceso en el código PHP?

Comment: <?PHP
$usuario = "ejemplo";
$contrasena = "000000";  
$servidor = "100.100.100.100";
$basededatos = "tabla";
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $contrasena ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
?> No tengo credenciales de acceso Solo es un form en html, pero a lo que voy no logra ni conectar y el codigo para conectar es el de arriba

Comment: Todo proveedor hosting y similar te proporciona tu usuario y tu clave de acceso de mysql (para que puedas cargar tu base de datos y configurar esos datos en tu conexión), de otra forma no vas a poder conectar tus scripts. Si no es el caso solo pídeles que te den uno. Y para ver detalles del error podrías en vez de usar mejor mysqli_error($conexion)

Comment: mira  la base de datos esta montada a un servidor dedicado(nuble) .

Comment: Esto suena a que la configuración de MySQL no acepta conexiones externas, o que no las acepta desde el alojamiento. Si tú MySQL está en el mismo equipo que el PHP, entonces prueba con `localhost` como servidor de BBDD. Sino vas a tener que poner la config de tu MySQL y explicar mejor como es la red que tiene ese host de pago